# Catch MySQL error when record does not exist in NodeJS

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I am trying to figure out how I can catch an error when a requested `id` is not found in the Database records.

My code is:

```
router.get('/users/:id', function(req, res) {

    getId = req.params.id

    db.con.query('SELECT * FROM employees where id=?', getId, function(err, results) {

       if (err) {
            console.log('error in query')
            return

        } else {
            obj = {
                id: results[0].id,
                name: results[0].name,
                location: results[0].location
                // error should be cached here when a requested results[0].id is not found
            }
            res.render('showuser');
        }
    })

});
```

In the console, I get the following error when a non-existed `id` is requested as it should be, however I cannot catch this error programmatically.

```
throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
^
ReferenceError: id is not defined
at Query._callback (C:\NodeJS\CRUD\CRUD-4\routes\add.js:21:13)
```

**Node**: v8.8.0

**Express**: v4.15.5

Comment: try printing the id using `console.log(req.params.id)` which will help you to see if the id is defined or not... plus initialize your getId variable `var getId`. add `;` at the end of the statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
try{
  obj = {
     id: results[0].id,
     name: results[0].name,
     location: results[0].location
  }
}catch(err){
  //handle error
}
```

`try {...}catch...` is how you handle exceptions in JavaScript. You can read more about it [here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch)

Answer (score 1):

```
// Error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(500).end(err.message);
}); 
...
router.get('/users/:id(\\d+)', function(req, res, next) {
    var id = req.params.id;

    db.con.query('SELECT * FROM employees where id= ?', id, function (err, results) {
       if (err) 
          return next(err);

       if (results.length == 0)
          return next(new Error('Incorrect id: ' + id));

        obj = {
            id: results[0].id,
            name: results[0].name,
            location: results[0].location
        }
        res.render('showuser', obj);
    });
})
```

Comment: What does `(\\d+)` stand for in `router.get` ?

Comment: @Cadmos it means `:id` must be a number (`\d`) and it's length must be greater than 0 (`+`)

Answer (score 1):

Try the code below:

```
router.get('/product/:id', function(req, res, next){
        try {
            const { idProduct } = req.body
            const [detailProduct] = await Product.detail(idProduct);
            if (detailProduct.length === 0) {
                return res.status(404).send({
                    status: "404",
                    msg: "Not found",
                    data: null
                });
            }
            return res.status(200).json(detailProduct[0])
        } catch (error) {
            if (!error.statusCode) {
                error.statusCode = 500
            }
            next(error)
        }
    }
```